# Is it the same queue if create the same name for queue in GCD?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Q1:Is it the same queue if create the same name for queue in GCD?

```
class Sample {
private var time:Int64 = 0
func asyncSerial(time:Int64){
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("test",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    dispatch_async(queue){
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, time)
        self.time = time
        print("async:\(self.time)")

        dispatch_after(delayTime, queue){
            print("wait:\(self.time)")

        }
    }

    print("sync:\(self.time)")
}
}

let s = Sample()
s.result(10)
let s2 = Sample()
s1.result(1)
```

I run it in playground(Xcode 7.1),and result:

### sync:100 async:100 sync:0 async:1 wait:100 wait:1

I thin the result should be :

### sync:100 sync:0 async:100 async:1 wait:100 wait:1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `label` is just for logging and debugging purposes.  For the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW66):

> A string label to attach to the queue to uniquely identify it in
>   debugging tools such as Instruments, sample, stackshots, and crash
>   reports. Because applications, libraries, and frameworks can all
>   create their own dispatch queues, a reverse-DNS naming style
>   (com.example.myqueue) is recommended. This parameter is optional and
>   can be NULL.

You are creating a new queue each time you call the `dispatch_queue_create` function.  This queue will be released after the function exits and the last block has completed execution since you are only holding the reference in a local variable.

The reason you get a variable output is that both blocks of code may execute concurrently and both update the `self.time` property.  Sometimes the first print executes before the second invocation has set the property to 1 (so you get "10,1") and sometimes the property has already been set to 1 before the first print executes, so you get "1,1".

Comment: ,If always create a new queue,Should the result be 1,10?

Comment: @Leo - No, because you've dispatched it asynchronously. It's a different queue each time, but the same `Sample` object. By the time your first `dispatch_after` block runs, you've apparently already updated `self.time` the second time.

Comment: @Rob,I update my question.,and the result seem not the same with expected. If  create new queue every-time, the result should be:'sync:100 sync:0 async:100 async:1 wait:1 wait:100'

'

Comment: Why?  The order of execution of tasks on different queues is non-deterministic.

Comment: @Leo - No, you have no assurances of when these asynchronous tasks complete with respect to the main queue.

Comment: @Rob-Could not  'dispatch_after'  keep the order?  The first call waiting for 100,and the second call waiting for 1. Is my usage wrong?

Comment: You are using a serial dispatch queue, so tasks will be executed in order for a given queue, but there is no relationship between task execution across different queues.  Also your print statements may report in a different order than actual execution because they are probably dispatched via another queue within the runtime